# What are the benefits available in itextsharp.dll commercial license than in open source

Tags: itext

I am developing a tool. i want to know the benefits available in itextsharp.dll commercial license than in open source.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Open source license is AGPL. If you extend their source or link to the binary you need to open source your code as well.